# Реализация верхнего меню

Tags: css, вёрстка, инспекция-кода

На днях набросал код верхнего меню без использования скриптов. Всё работает на ура, но правильно ли это? Дело в том, что я использовал для стилизации `input type="checkbox"`, `pointer-events: none;` и много чего ещё. Имеет ли такая реализация место в проектах или всё же лучше использовать JS для таких ситуаций?

Код меню:

```css
body {
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial
}
.topbar {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.topbar__button-open-leftmenu {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.topbar__button-open-leftmenu:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1C90F3;
}
.topbar__button-open-leftmenu svg path {
  fill: #333;
}
.topbar__button-open-leftmenu:hover svg path {
  fill: #000;
}
.topbar__memu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.topbar__memu li {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}
.topbar__memu li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.topbar__memu li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.topbar__memu li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
#topbar__checked-search:checked ~ .topbar__memu li:nth-child(1) {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#topbar__checked-search:checked ~ .topbar__memu li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#topbar__checked-search:checked ~ .topbar__memu li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.topbar__memu-item {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.topbar__memu-item:hover {
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1C90F3;
}
.topbar__button-open-search {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.topbar__button-open-search:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.topbar__button-open-search svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.topbar__button-open-search svg path {
  fill: #333;
}
.topbar__button-open-search:hover svg path {
  fill: #000;
}
.topbar__button-open-search svg#icon-serach-close {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.topbar__button-open-search svg#icon-serach-open {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
#topbar__checked-search:checked ~ .topbar__button-open-search svg#icon-serach-close {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
#topbar__checked-search:checked ~ .topbar__button-open-search svg#icon-serach-open {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
#topbar__checked-search {
  display: none;
}
.topbar__search {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 60%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#topbar__checked-search:checked ~ .topbar__search {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.topbar__search-input {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 30px 0 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: inherit;
  outline: none;
  transition: background 0.2s ease;
}
.topbar__search-input:focus {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.topbar__search-button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  right: 12px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.topbar__search-button svg path {
  fill: #333;
}
.topbar__search-button:hover svg path {
  fill: #000;
}
.topbar__search-panel {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 42px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 42px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
#topbar__checked-search:checked ~ .topbar__search-panel {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.topbar__search-panel-list {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-20%);
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, opacity 0.4s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
#topbar__checked-search:checked ~ .topbar__search-panel .topbar__search-panel-list {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
}
.topbar__search-panel-list:before {
  display: block;
  content: 'Результаты поиска:';
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  color: #acacac;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
.topbar__search-panel-list-item {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.topbar__search-panel-list-item:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
/* Leftmenu */

.leftmenu {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 42px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 42px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
#topbar__checked-leftmenu:checked + .leftmenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.leftmenu__list {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
  transition: left 0.4s ease;
}
#topbar__checked-leftmenu:checked + .leftmenu .leftmenu__list {
  left: 0;
}
.leftmenu__list-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.leftmenu__list-item:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.leftmenu__hidemenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <label for="topbar__checked-leftmenu" class="topbar__button-open-leftmenu">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <path d="M 16 6 C 14.895431 6 14 6.8954305 14 8 C 14 9.1045695 14.895431 10 16 10 C 17.104569 10 18 9.1045695 18 8 C 18 6.8954305 17.104569 6 16 6 z M 16 14 C 14.895431 14 14 14.895431 14 16 C 14 17.104569 14.895431 18 16 18 C 17.104569 18 18 17.104569 18 16 C 18 14.895431 17.104569 14 16 14 z M 16 22 C 14.895431 22 14 22.895431 14 24 C 14 25.104569 14.895431 26 16 26 C 17.104569 26 18 25.104569 18 24 C 18 22.895431 17.104569 22 16 22 z"></path>
    </svg>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="topbar__checked-search">
  <ul class="topbar__memu">
    <li><a href="" class="topbar__memu-item">Пункт 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" class="topbar__memu-item">Пункт 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" class="topbar__memu-item">Пункт 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="topbar__search">
    <input type="text" class="topbar__search-input" placeholder="Найти...">
    <button class="topbar__search-button">
      <svg version="1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M 9 2 C 5.1 2 2 5.1 2 9 C 2 12.9 5.1 16 9 16 C 10.722428 16 12.28779 15.386196 13.5 14.375 L 14 14.875 L 14 15.6875 L 20.3125 22 L 22 20.3125 L 15.6875 14 L 14.8125 14 L 14.34375 13.53125 C 15.372135 12.314388 16 10.738606 16 9 C 16 5.1 12.9 2 9 2 z M 9 4 C 11.8 4 14 6.2 14 9 C 14 11.8 11.8 14 9 14 C 6.2 14 4 11.8 4 9 C 4 6.2 6.2 4 9 4 z"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
  <label for="topbar__checked-search" class="topbar__button-open-search">
    <svg id="icon-serach-close" version="1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M 9 2 C 5.1 2 2 5.1 2 9 C 2 12.9 5.1 16 9 16 C 10.722428 16 12.28779 15.386196 13.5 14.375 L 14 14.875 L 14 15.6875 L 20.3125 22 L 22 20.3125 L 15.6875 14 L 14.8125 14 L 14.34375 13.53125 C 15.372135 12.314388 16 10.738606 16 9 C 16 5.1 12.9 2 9 2 z M 9 4 C 11.8 4 14 6.2 14 9 C 14 11.8 11.8 14 9 14 C 6.2 14 4 11.8 4 9 C 4 6.2 6.2 4 9 4 z"></path>
    </svg>
    <svg id="icon-serach-open" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <path style="text-indent:0;text-align:start;line-height:normal;text-transform:none;block-progression:tb;-inkscape-font-specification:Bitstream Vera Sans" d="M 8.71875 7.28125 L 7.28125 8.71875 L 14.5625 16 L 7.28125 23.28125 L 8.71875 24.71875 L 16 17.4375 L 23.28125 24.71875 L 24.71875 23.28125 L 17.4375 16 L 24.71875 8.71875 L 23.28125 7.28125 L 16 14.5625 L 8.71875 7.28125 z"
      color="#000" overflow="visible" font-family="Bitstream Vera Sans"></path>
    </svg>
  </label>
  <div class="topbar__search-panel">
    <div class="topbar__search-panel-list">
      <a href="#" class="topbar__search-panel-list-item">Обои для рабочего стола</a>
      <a href="#" class="topbar__search-panel-list-item">Новости</a>
      <a href="#" class="topbar__search-panel-list-item">StackOverflow</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="topbar__checked-leftmenu">
<div class="leftmenu">
  <ul class="leftmenu__list">
    <li><a href="#" class="leftmenu__list-item">Пункт 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="leftmenu__list-item">Пункт 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="leftmenu__list-item">Пункт 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <label for="topbar__checked-leftmenu" class="leftmenu__hidemenu"></label>
</div>
```

Если кто знает, как реализовать такое более качественно, то буду рад поучиться :)

Comment: Относительно pure-css менюшек в принципе, их делать можно, но штука это крайне негибкая, поэтому во многих больших проектах от них постепенно избавляются.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, я проверил, мои анимации работают с тех версий браузеров, где появился уже transition и transform

Comment: про негибкость я говорю не в плане кроссбраузерности, а в том плане что когда надо будет резко переделать меню - возникнут проблемы

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, уверяю. Я знаю свой код и если мне нужно будет что-то изменить, то лично у меня проблем не будет :)

Comment: Вы - наивный студент без минимального опыта коммерческой командной разработки) Поэтому гибкость для Вас - пустой звук. Вот для многих - это не пустой звук. Это не претензия к конкретной цсс менюшке, я говорю почему цсс менюшки не очень в принципе.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, я не студент, я - школьник :) Но про гибкость я знаю и знаю, как сделать код легко читаемым, но это куча мороки для меня )

Comment: гибкость - это проблема куда сложнее чем просто читаемость, увы. Я боюсь если Вы не понимаете проблематики, моего красноречия не хватит, чтобы донести ее)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, можете расписать все плюсы и минусы моего решения в ответе, и привести свой размышления по этому поводу, что бы другие знали, как лучше делать :)

Comment: мне лень, и я никогда не делаю хитрые менюшки на чистом цсс) Именно по причине которую я описал выше.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, утка-утка, какой же вы тогда пользователь SO, если вам лень для любимых пользователь расписать лаконичный ответ)

Comment: Ленивый. Мне интересно писать подробный и точный ответ на интересные мне темы или где все сразу видно, это - неинтересная мне тема)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, тогда чё пишете?) Ладно, може кто ответит по своему мнению, раз вам лень)

Comment: Я вкратце отвечаю на ваш вопрос: "Имеет ли такая реализация место в проектах или всё же лучше использовать JS для таких ситуаций?". Мой ответ: для демок, кусков которые никто никогда не будет сильно менять или просто поиграться - так можно. Для нормальных проектов - лучше для хитрых действий использовать js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В современном web приложении js кода непомерно много, и, моё мнение - если есть возможность писать без js - пишите без js. В том числе и меню.

1. Если вы напишете на css меню - оно будет быстрее.
2. Вероятность краша программы, который остановит всю работу приложения
   будет существенно снижена.
3. Написать css меню быстрее чем на js.

Когда стоит написать меню js.
Вам надо написать крутое меню которое имеет ряд функционала (нажатие по кнопки как описано выше, задержка при потере курсора мыши, итд).

Но все простые всплывашки если можно обойтись без js надо писать без js. 
Это не только моё мнение, детально, почему стоит уменьшить объём  js кода рассказано в этой [статье](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/07/10-very-good-reasons-to-stop-using-javascript/).

Comment: Ваш ответ вызывает у меня очень неоднозначную реакцию. С одной стороны я согласен с тем что если можно не писать js код, лучше наверное не писать js код. Чисто css и проще, и для всего простого стоит использовать чисто css. А теперь "но". Если у вас что-то сложнее лендинга Васи Пупкина, то без js не обойтись. Количество реальных прикладных задач где достаточно css-only решений - очень мало. Поэтому я не стал бы рекомендовать их использовать.

Comment: Нет, я имел ввиду именно уменьшить использование js, а не Не использовать его вообще. "Количество реальных прикладных задач где достаточно css-only решений - очень мало." - в этом вся и суть. Где есть возможность css решить проблему то решаем её css. Для всего остального есть js. Я, например, пишу на Angular2, но простые выпадашки я стараюсь решить css. Потому что если я буду - это всё Ангуляре то минимизированный код станет больше, его потом надо будет как то нарезать на бандлы.

Comment: Вот хитрые менюшки - это то место где логика порой меняется. Я на css их бы делать не стал. Увеличение размера js кода при добавлении менюшки будет несущественным, если Вы конечно для этого из npm что-то не затянете))

Comment: Тут,наверное,по ситуации надо смотреть. Если меню настолько простое что его можно сделать на css, почему бы так не сделать. Конечно, если меню динамическое, вёрстка сложная, то заморачиваться с css не стоит.

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, вы правы. Но задержку при потере курсора тоже можно на CSS сделать :)

Comment: Да, конечно )) я и  имел ввиду http://getinstance.info/articles/css/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/

Answer (score 1):

Использование `<input type="checkbox" />` + `<label>` — это в первую очередь хак. У данного приема есть, по-моему, только одно использование без нарушения семантики — это кастомные чекбоксы и радиокнопки. Во всех остальных случаях, использование такого приема при возможности сделать семантическую разметку является плохим тоном, потому что:

1. Страдает доступность; ваше меню недоступно при помощи клавиатуры, а следовательно и для экранных читалок. Незрячих людей или людей с проблемами со зрением, которые пользуются специальным софтом и устройствами, гораздо больше, чем может казаться, а в некоторых западных странах доступность является государственным требованием.
2. Появляется дополнительная разметка.
3. Модульность кода ставится под сомнение, поскольку появляются дополнительные жестко связанные между собой элементы.
4. Чекбокс используется вне формы и не по назначению (т. е. не служит для отправки массива данных на сервер), что, вероятно, может вызвать проблемы в какой-нибудь CMS, которая автоматически оборачивает элементы формы тегом `<form>` (первое, что приходит в голову).

P.S. прятать меню за кнопкой-гамбургером само по себе [сомнительное UI-решение](http://jamesarcher.me/hamburger-menu).

Comment: Не согласен в корне, так как,  не используя css прийдётся писать js,а лучший код на js - это не написанный js. Поэтому всё что можно сделать средствами css - это правильно.

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick «лучший код на js - это не написанный js» ШТО.

Comment: впрочем, это ваша точка зрения, мне просто хотелось бы узнать её детальнее, желательно даже отдельным ответом.

Comment: добавил развёрнутый ответ

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko *"Ваше меню недоступно при помощи клавиатуры"* — сомнительный довод.  Попробовал пройтись с помощью клавиши Tab по меню, всё работало. Даже если бы не работало, то можно бы доработать. И это никак не было связано с тем, что не использовался JS. Поэтому весь первый довод "про незрячих и т.д." считаю недействительным.

Answer (score 1):

По мне, такое решение - не совсем оправдано. Оно может иметь место в качестве материала для общего развития, тренировок, но не для релизного проекта. Почему? Потому что это **велосипед**, **хак**, который сложно контролировать, в том плане, если вы открыли где-нибудь пункт меню, то как связать это с остальными элементами? Через JS, очевидно. А раз использование этого подразумевает скрипты, то проще и решить это скриптами. Тем более, что для меню это пара строчек.
- Доводы в пользу того, что мол а как же мобильные юзвери - нынешние мобилки помощнее среднего пк пару лет назад, поедать код тоннами они научены, не думаю, что стоит экономить на наносекундах, получая в ответ негибкое, плохо масштабируемое решение.
 - Про то что контент не индексируется, это бред, [гуголь давно всему научился](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more).
 - "Если JS" упадет - это приведет к останову всей страницы. Тоже сомнительно. Не в том плане, что не приведет, а в том, что непоставленная скобка, что в JS, что в CSS приведет к неправильной работе компонентов, отсюда - проблема выедена из яйца. (Да и мы ведь не кидаем код в продакшн, предварительно не *протестив* его, верно?)
 - "JS требует времени на разработку" - *css does the same*. CSS также нуждается во времени на верстку, разработку, подгонку, разница лишь в том, что JS предоставляет куда более обширный инструментарий, позволяя решать идентичные задачи *быстрее*.

Comment: Про то что контент не индексируется - не бред. По факту гугл умеет индексировать сложные синглпейджи очень плохо. Подробности смотри например тут: https://habrahabr.ru/post/301288/

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму можешь не трудиться, с лету нашел 2 статьи, на том же хабре, что все отлично индексируется, стоит только подумать и поработать.

Comment: Мир живет не одним гуглом. Научиться индексировать синглпейджи можно, но это требует значительных усилий. Проблема в источнике возможно слегка преувеличена, но она вполне реальна и не является полностью надуманной. Кстати приведите ваши ссылки, я свою - привел.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму [Раз](https://habrahabr.ru/post/254213/), [два](https://habrahabr.ru/post/219875/). И да, очень плохо - не значит, не умеет. Даже в твоей статье проскакивали комменты с решениями

Comment: спасибо за ссылки, я посмотрел. В статьях приведенных вами поисковику подсовывается срендеренный phantomjs на сервере снепшот, в котором js по сути нету, и работа с механизмами индексации js гугла не рассматривается. В отличие от приведенной мной статьи.

Comment: Отдельно отмечу что сервер сайд рендеринг для целей seo - это подход нормальный. Но в современном мире это принято делать несколько по-другому, в обеих приведенных вами статьях на первый взгляд наворочены лютые костыли.

Comment: Что еще раз подтверждает мой тезис - индексировать приложение со сложным js можно, но иногда это чертовски сложно.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму так а что надо то? Там рассказывается как индексировать ajax контент. Подгружать контент ajax'ом тоже может показаться костылем, а если присмотреться - фичей. Так же и там. И да, я не говорил, что SPA не индексируются гуглом, а указал, что индексировать их он умеет. Плохо или хорошо - другая история, выходы есть, пускай с виду костыльные, но они есть и работоспособны. В любом случае, проблемы индексации SPA не являются краеугольным камнем в создании велосипедов на `CSS`. Как то так `=)`

Comment: Фраза "Про то что контент не индексируется, это бред" звучит для меня слишком однозначно. Это конечно спорное утверждение, но не бред, что я и пытаюсь сказать. Я если что, тоже против цсс велосипедов. Вы говорите "гугл умеет индексировать spa". Я говорю - "гугл умеет индексировать спа, но при этом столько 'если', что на это полагаться не стоит"

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму да гугл и обычные страницы неплохо индексирует, однако там тоже не все так просто, и оказывается тоже присутствует немало "если". Недостаточно просто внизу странички написать `ключевые слова: вася пупкин, был, здесь, ксс меню`. Нельзя же сказать `язык программирования может решить очень многие задачи, но при этом столько "если", что полагаться на него не стоит`

Comment: Ладно, стоп холивар, я думаю мы друг друга поняли в общих чертах.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, а я всё же прошу вас добавить собственный ответ :)